# How can I use only few attributes of Django User Model?

Tags: django-models

I want to get rid of the existing fields in the Django's in-built user model like, is_staff, last_login etc, and keep only the username and password. How can I do this in a clean way?

Comment: Extend `AbstractBaseUser`

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to add a queryset from one model to the UserModel. But as the attributes are mismatched in the 2 models the error is getting raised.

Comment: `AbstractBaseUser` should have no implemented fields. So it's empty, Add the fields you want and it should work.